# UIWebView in IOS (Xamarin monotuch)

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am sure that this has been asked before but i am unable to get to a solution.

I have a UIWebView which is wrapped inside a UIView.

The web view loads HTML - Tapping on the HTML link results in certain action (Done. Detect the click in ShouldStartLoad and act accordingly).

Tapping anywhere else other than a link should result in another action - This is where i am having an issue. Just cant seem to get the tap gesture to work (on the UIWebView or the wrapper UIView)

Any clues?

Regards
Sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding tap gesture recognizers is not an easy task due to the way it works internally (UIKit view hierarchy and WebKit view hierarchy).

I would suggest a much simpler solution. Add [Hammer.js](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js) to your HTML (or inject it in `webViewDidFinishLoad:`), and on tap events, send a fake load request and catch like with links.

```
Hammer(el).on("tap", function() {
    //Send fake request here.
});
```